# Java switch statement <identifier> issue

Tags: java, switch-statement, identifier

The point of this program is for a user to enter three exam scores and their average and letter grade is returned to them.

The way it is currently written gives me an  error for the 'public static String getLetterGrade..' line and I don't know why that is..

```
public class GradeProblem
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 char letterGrade;
 String exam1, exam2, exam3;
 double exam1Score, exam2Score, exam3Score, average; 

 exam1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your score for Exam 1: ");
 exam1Score = Double.parseDouble(exam1.substring(0,2));
 int intExam1Score = (int)exam1Score;

 exam2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your score for Exam 2: ");
 exam2Score = Double.parseDouble(exam2.substring(0,2));
 int intExam2Score = (int)exam2Score;

 exam3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your score for Exam 3: ");
 exam3Score = Double.parseDouble(exam3.substring(0,2));
 int intExam3Score = (int)exam3Score;

 average = (intExam1Score + intExam2Score + intExam3Score) / 3;

 int intAvergage = (int)average;
 letterGrade = getLetterGrade(intAverage);

 System.out.println("Your average is "+average);  
 System.out.println("Your letter grade is "+letterGrade); 

 }

 private static String getLetterGrade(average)
 {
String letterGrade;
switch(intAverage/10)
{
    case 10: letterGrade = "A";
    case 9: letterGrade = "A";
              break;
    case 8: letterGrade = "B";
              break;
    case 7: letterGrade = "C";
              break;
    case 6: letterGrade = "D";
    default:
              letterGrade = "E";
}
return letterGrade;

   }
```

Comment: You are missing the data type for the parameter "average"

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
 private static String getLetterGrade(int average){
```

or with any datatype, and you are referring to another non exist variable in switch statement `intAverage`

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String getLetterGrade(int average)
```

You forgot to enter the type of variable `average`, it needs to be type `int` I assume.

switch(intAverage/10) needs to be changed to switch(average/10).

I'm also seeing some problems with your choice of int messing with accuracy unless that's something you want to ignore. I'd use if statements and a range for the switch cases, rather than just casting them all to ints. Maybe it makes a difference maybe it doesn't but all that casting and loss of accuracy just makes me feel like the code is incomplete.

Comment: average is an int, not a String.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `average` has no type. It should be:

```
private static String getLetterGrade(int average) {
```

to match the type of the variable you're passing to it.

Comment: He never use this variable. I guess he have to use `average` inside the `switch` statement.